# What is the reason behind to fail aggregate report but view results in tree is all pass in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

While i was running a script with 6 Thread groups for 1hr.
I got all pass in View result tree but fail in Aggregate report. tried in both ways in GUI and Non-GUI mode. results are same.
now i am confused that what could be the root cause behind it. is it scrpit/data related issue of performance related issue? or something else?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have 19589 sample results in [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report)
2. You have 27 sample results in [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

Try scrolling down and maybe you will get the failure detail.

Alternatively you can just tick `Errors` box and it will not show passed sample results and you will see only failures.

[image]

Also View Results Tree listener can display only 500 results by default, if you want to be able to see them all - you will need to set `view.results.tree.max_results` [JMeter property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) to `0` and restart JMeter to pick up the change